error en proyecto de anguular
me aparece lo siguiente:

ng serve --port 9002 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

Error: /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/reportUnhandledError.js:13
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find builder "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application-esbuil".
at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:145:19)
at name (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:220:40)
at Observable._subscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/jobs/create-job-handler.js:107:26)
at Observable._trySubscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:41:25)
at /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:35:31
at Object.errorContext (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/errorContext.js:22:9)
at Observable.subscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:26:24)
at /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:17:63
at OperatorSubscriber._this._next (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:33:21)
at Subscriber.next (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:51:18)
Node.js v20.11.1
 ✘ Preview failed to start
 Starting preview...
Waiting for your web server to start serving

myapp@0.0.0 start
ng serve --port 9002 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

Error: /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/reportUnhandledError.js:13
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find builder "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application-esbuil".
at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:145:19)
at name (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:220:40)
at Observable._subscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/jobs/create-job-handler.js:107:26)
at Observable._trySubscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:41:25)
at /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:35:31
at Object.errorContext (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/errorContext.js:22:9)
at Observable.subscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:26:24)
at /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:17:63
at OperatorSubscriber._this._next (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:33:21)
at Subscriber.next (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:51:18)
Error:
Node.js v20.11.1
 ✘ Preview failed to start
Installing extensions...
Extension 'angular.ng-template' v18.2.0 is already installed. Use '--force' option to update to latest version or provide '@' to install a specific version, for example: 'angular.ng-template@1.2.3'.
 Starting preview...
Waiting for your web server to start serving

myapp@0.0.0 start
ng serve --port 9002 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

Error: /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/reportUnhandledError.js:13
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find builder "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application-esbuil".
at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:145:19)
at name (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:220:40)
at Observable._subscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/jobs/create-job-handler.js:107:26)
at Observable._trySubscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:41:25)
at /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:35:31
at Object.errorContext (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/errorContext.js:22:9)
at Observable.subscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:26:24)
at /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:17:63
at OperatorSubscriber._this._next (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:33:21)
at Subscriber.next (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:51:18)
Node.js v20.11.1
 ✘ Preview failed to start
 Starting preview...
Waiting for your web server to start serving

myapp@0.0.0 start
ng serve --port 9002 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

Error: /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/reportUnhandledError.js:13
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find builder "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application-esbuil".
at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:145:19)
at name (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:220:40)
at Observable._subscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/jobs/create-job-handler.js:107:26)
at Observable._trySubscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:41:25)
at /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:35:31
at Object.errorContext (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/errorContext.js:22:9)
at Observable.subscribe (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:26:24)
at /home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:17:63
at OperatorSubscriber._this._next (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:33:21)
at Subscriber.next (/home/user/angular0/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:51:18)
Error:
Node.js v20.11.1
 ✘ Preview failed to start

Tienes un error, te falta la letra D:
@angular-devkit/build-angular:application-esbuil

debería ser:
@angular-devkit/build-angular:application-esbuild

Si te sigue saltando error, reinstala las dependencias:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install


Ya lo puse, le rinstalé y me sigue saliendo error

@KayllerJohanMosqueraAlvarez actualiza la pregunta. Muestra el código (como texto) donde esta saliendo el error.
